# How does Lucene build its inverted index so rapidly

Tags: search-algorithms, edit-distance

I am writing a small Ruby on Rails engine that does simple full-text search. When someone imports text from a given model (eg. Articles, Posts, etc) an inverted index is built that looks like the following:

```
Term        Doc. info               Doc. frequency  Spelling suggestions
appear      {:title=>[1], :body=>[1, 2, 3]}     4   ["appears"]
success     {:title=>[1], :body=>[1]}           2   ["successful", "success"]
year        {:body=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}               4   ["yearly", "year"]
synonym     {:body=>[1]}                        1   ["synonymous"]
fashion     {:body=>[1]}                        1   ["fashion"]
tv          {:body=>[1, 2]}                     2   ["tv"]
drama       {:body=>[1]}                        1   ["dramas"]
aesthet     {:body=>[1]}                        1   ["aesthetics"]
```

where the term is the stemmed version of the imported word, the doc info are the document ids and fields where the term appears, the frequency is the sum of occurrences and the spelling suggestions are the original (unstemmed word) which I will later be using for spelling suggestions (using [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)).

This import process can take ~20 seconds for several thousand words.

My question is, how is it possible that [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) can rapidly tokenize and build an inverted index for several *thousand documents* within a fraction of the time that it's taking me? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the algorithm(s) / code you are using to import. My guess is that somewhere you've got a $O(n^2)$ (or worse) step. Are you looping over all spelling suggestions for a word for all inserted words or something? What does profiling show? Also note that Ruby tends to be (really really really) slow at the best of times.

Comment: Yes I'm basically taking text fields, splitting on white space and stemming those words. Then I add the words to an ActiveRecord row one by one as shown in the snippet above. Can't think of any other way to do this really...

Comment: Again, either code or profiling information, or actual inputs, or all of them, would really be needed to say much more.

Comment: I guess my question isn't so much about how I can improve *my* code specifically, but rather how is Lucene stemming, tokenizing, indexing and adding doc frequency data so rapidly that it is virtually a near instantaneous process? Is there some document that outlines this process/chain of steps that leads to a documented index?